# OLA API integration in Ruby on Rails web API {"code":"invalid_partner_key","message":"Partner key is not authorized"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, access-token, httparty

I am passing the basic URL required to call OLA API with x app token in HTTParty, but it gives this error:

```
{"code":"invalid_partner_key","message":"Partner key is not authorized"}
```

Here is the code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    lat = params[:lat].to_s
    long = params[:long].to_s

    @results = HTTParty.get("https://api.uber.com/v1/products?server_token=my_token&latitude="+lat+"&longitude="+long).parsed_response
    @result1 = HTTParty.get("https://devapi.olacabs.com/v1/products?X-APP-TOKEN=my_token&pickup_lat=12.9491416&pickup_lng=77.64298").parsed_response

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => JSON.parse(@results) }
      format.json { render :json => JSON.parse(@result1) }
      format.html { render "index.html.erb" }
    end
  end
end
```

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Going through the olacabs docs, your `X-APP-TOKEN` should be passed as a header and not along with the payload. So you should be doing something like this

```
query = { 
  "pickup_lat" => 12.9491416,
  "pickup_lng" => 77.64298
}

headers = { 
  "X-APP-TOKEN" => your_token
}

@result1 = HTTParty.get(
  "https://devapi.olacabs.com/v1/products", 
  :query => query,
  :headers => headers
).parsed_response
```

I didn't test this out but should give a good start to figuring your issue out.

Comment: still not working . same error again: {"code":"invalid_partner_key","message":"Partner key is not authorized"}

Comment: did you pass your token as a string? `"your_token"`